# Validating forms with regex in codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

How can I validate a form using regex in codeiginiter. I'd like to check the input against:

```
^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

I'm assuming the best way is in some sort of callback. I tried a bunch of ideas on the web but I can't seem to get any working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
function validateRegex($input)
{
  if (preg_match('/^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/', $input))
  {
    return true; // it matched, return true or false if you want opposite
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In your controller, you can use it like:

```
if ($this->validateRegex($this->input->post('some_data')))
{
  // true, proceed with rest of the code.....
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Old post but you can add the regex directly in the input validation rule

`$this->form_validation->set_rules()`

Add to function above: `regex_match[your regex]`

Answer (score 1):

How about using AJAX?

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>regex_check", { username: $("#username").val() }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

The regex_check function would have a typical regex check in it, like

```
function regex_check(){
    $this->get->post('username');
    if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-] +\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$', $username)){
       return TRUE;}else{return FALSE;}
    }
```

You would only allow successful submission of form if all data is validated.

These code snippets should help you on the track to validating the data.

Comment: thanks for the interesting solution, though not the most Codeigniter-centric

Answer (score 1):

here's a full solution submitting to `account/signup`

in the `account` controller:

```
function signup(){
    if($_POST){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'Full Name', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback_check_password');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){            
            echo validation_errors();       
        }
        else{
          // form validates, now can do stuff such as insert into database 
          // and show the user that they successfully signed up, i.e.,:
          // $this->load->view('account/signup_success');
       }
    }
}
```

`check_password` callback function also in the `account` controller:

```
function check_password($p){ 
      $p = $this->input->post('password');
      if (preg_match('/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8}/', $p)) return true;
      // it matched, see <ul> below for interpreting this regex   
      else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password', 
            '<span class="error">
                <ul id="passwordError">
                    <li> Password must be at least:</li>
                    <li> 8 characters</li>
                    <li> 1 upper, 1 lower case letter</li>
                    <li> 1 number</li>  
                </ul>               
            </span>');
        return false;
      } 
}
```